# Making This Javascript Countdown Timer Responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently using a modified version of a JS countdown element for a site coming up. I've been learning a ton of how to use flex grids but haven't done a lot with block/inline-block, etc.

Currently when the countdown hits around 945px, the 4 inline-block boxes stay as 4 columns and end up overflowing to the edge of the screen: 
[image]

My desired result would be at around 945px, the 4 columns would collapse to 2 side by side, with the text still being under their proper boxes. I was messing around altering the code in "inspect" in chrome and accidentally succeeded in doing this, but the 4 lines of text were still below the element with the boxes rather than in their proper place. Here is what my desired result looks like:

[image]

Here is the code:

https://codepen.io/Lancewalker/pen/QxpbZx

```js
$(function (){

function countdown() {

var now = new Date();
var eventDate = new Date(2019, 0, 1);
var currentTime = now.getTime();
var evenTime = eventDate.getTime();

var remTime = evenTime - currentTime;

var sec = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
var min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
var hur = Math.floor(min / 60);
var day = Math.floor(hur / 24);

 hur %= 24;
 min %= 60;
 sec %= 60;

hur = (hur < 10) ? "0" + hur : hur;
min = (min < 10) ? "0" + min : min;
sec = (sec < 10) ? "0" + sec : sec;

$('.seconds').text(sec);
$('.minutes').text(min);
$('.hours').text(hur);
$('.days').text(day);

setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
}

countdown();
});
```

```css
    body {
    background-color: #333;
}
    .container {
    width: 800px;
    height: 350px;
    margin:  auto;
    text-align: center
}

    .container h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Exo, Arial, Sans-serif;
    padding: 50px 0 20px;
    font-weight: normal
}

    .container .content {
    width: 100%;
}

    .container .content > div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 35px 10px 0;
    width: 120px;
    height: 130px;
    background: rgb(146, 163, 191, .6);
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 138px;
    font-family: Exo, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 55px;
}

    .container .title {
    width: ;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative
}

    .container .title span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 140px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Exo', arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <h2>Apartments Coming Soon!</h2>
     <div class="content">
       <div class="days">85</div>
       <div class="hours">22</div>
       <div class="minutes">33</div>
       <div class="seconds">54</div>
     </div>
     <div class="title">
       <span>Days</span>
       <span>Hours</span>
       <span>Minutes</span>
       <span>Seconds</span>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have your `.container` class width set as a hard 800px value for starters.

```
.container {
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 350px;
    margin:  auto;
    text-align: center
}
```

Making this simple change will have your timer squares start to collapse underneath. You will have to make some more changes yourself but I would look into media queries and responsive design with %. Anytime you hard code a number such as 800px you will run into issues when you get to a smaller size.

I would also consider refactoring your HTML so that the time squares and titles are together.

```
<div class="time-square">
    <div class="time-square-time">88</div>
    <div class="time-square-title">Days</div>
</div>
```

You will be able to move your HTML around a little more cleanly this way, you are going to run into a few issues matching the title to the time in your current structure

Comment: Oh very cool. Thanks! I took the JS and HTMl structure from a codepen which was obviously not responsive to start.. The only reason I am having trouble is because I didn't write the thing from scratch myself (mostly due to having 0 knowledge of javascript). Otherwise, I normally use flex grids because I really love how easy they are to use. I don't have time to convert the entire thing to a flexgrid while figuring out how to implement the javascript, so I'm trying to reconfigure the code I found to make it responsive. Thanks for your help

Comment: Definitely wrap the time and text together + 1

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest restructuring your markup slightly - wrapping the number and the text ('day', 'hour', etc) in the same parent. This will ensure they stay together when content is wrapped.

For the CSS, change `width: 800px` to `max-width` - this ensure the content resizes on screens smaller than 800px.

You can then use CSS Grid to layout the boxes and simplify the code.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RJpWdB)

```js
$(function() {

  function countdown() {

    var now = new Date();
    var eventDate = new Date(2019, 0, 1);
    var currentTime = now.getTime();
    var evenTime = eventDate.getTime();

    var remTime = evenTime - currentTime;

    var sec = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
    var min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
    var hur = Math.floor(min / 60);
    var day = Math.floor(hur / 24);

    hur %= 24;
    min %= 60;
    sec %= 60;

    hur = (hur < 10) ? "0" + hur : hur;
    min = (min < 10) ? "0" + min : min;
    sec = (sec < 10) ? "0" + sec : sec;

    $('.seconds').text(sec);
    $('.minutes').text(min);
    $('.hours').text(hur);
    $('.days').text(day);

    setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
  }

  countdown();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.container h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Exo, Arial, Sans-serif;
  padding: 50px 0 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 120px);
  /* use grid gap instead of margin around boxes */
  grid-gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box>div {
  height: 130px;
  background: rgb(146, 163, 191, 0.6);
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Exo, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  /* use flexbox instead of lineheight for vertical centering */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Exo", arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Apartments Coming Soon!</h2>
  <div class="content">

    <div class="box">
      <div class="days">85</div>
      <span>Days</span>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="hours">22</div>
      <span>Hours</span>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="minutes">33</div>
      <span>Minutes</span>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="seconds">54</div>
      <span>Seconds</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split into to two parts of div, it will looks fine.

If I misunderstood your question, please let me know.

```js
$(function (){

function countdown() {

var now = new Date();
var eventDate = new Date(2019, 0, 1);
var currentTime = now.getTime();
var evenTime = eventDate.getTime();

var remTime = evenTime - currentTime;

var sec = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
var min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
var hur = Math.floor(min / 60);
var day = Math.floor(hur / 24);

 hur %= 24;
 min %= 60;
 sec %= 60;

hur = (hur < 10) ? "0" + hur : hur;
min = (min < 10) ? "0" + min : min;
sec = (sec < 10) ? "0" + sec : sec;

$('.seconds').text(sec);
$('.minutes').text(min);
$('.hours').text(hur);
$('.days').text(day);

setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
}

countdown();
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #333;
}
    .container {
    width: 800px;
    height: 350px;
    margin:  auto;
    text-align: center
}

    .container h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Exo, Arial, Sans-serif;
    padding: 50px 0 20px;
    font-weight: normal
}

    .container .content {
    width: 100%;
}

    .container .content > div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 35px 10px 0;
    width: 120px;
    height: 130px;
    background: rgb(146, 163, 191, .6);
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 138px;
    font-family: Exo, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 55px;
}

    .container .title {
    width: ;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative
}

    .container .title span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 140px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Exo', arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
     <h2>Apartments Coming Soon!</h2>
     <div class="content">
       <div class="days">85</div>
       <div class="hours">22</div>
     </div>
     <div class="title">
       <span>Days</span>
       <span>Hours</span>
     </div>
     <div class="content">
       <div class="minutes">33</div>
       <div class="seconds">54</div>
     </div>
     <div class="title">
       <span>Minutes</span>
       <span>Seconds</span>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CSS Media Queries** like following:

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
 .container .content > div, .container .title span {
  width: 20%;
 }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
 .container .content > div, .container .title span {
  width: 50%;
 }
}
```